# Parametric form defined by reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm doing some problems where I need to compute the eigen vector from the eigen values of a matrix.

I am having trouble wrapping my brain around a fundamental concept of converting the reduced row echelon form (rref) into the eigen vector.

In one example, the rref form of $(A-\lambda)x=0$ is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

From this it makes sense that 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}\\
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
    -x_{3}\\
    0 \\
    x_{3} (i.e.,free) \\
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

However, when the rref form for a matrix $A-\lambda$ is $I^{4}$:
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
    1 & 4 & 1 & 3\\
    3 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
    1 & 3 & 1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$I^{4} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigen vector is 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}\\
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3} \\
    x_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Based on the *notation* I would expect the eigen vector in the second case to be $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I feel that I don't understand this notation correctly, what am I missing?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need to reduce matrix $A-\lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue instead of matrix $A$.

Comment: By definition an eigenvector is a nonzero vector, so the conclusion in the case where $(A-\lambda I)$ is nonsingular (has rref the identity matrix) is that $\lambda$ is not a eigenvalue of $A$ (and there are no eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$).

Comment: Adding to Gribouillis’ comment, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. That aside, you can find by inspection that an eigenvector is $[1,1,1,1]^T$: the row sums of $A$ are all equal, and summing the rows is equivalent to right-multiplying by a vector of all ones.

Comment: This is clear, but if I replace the 1’s in the rref form of A-lambda with xi’s, it reads as though all xi = 0.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then the rref of $A-\lambda I$ cannot be the identity: $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ has a non-trivial solution, which is equivalent to $A-\lambda I$ being rank-deficient. If you’re ending up with the identity matrix as the rref, then you’re making an error somewhere along the way, either in your computation of eigenvalues or in the row-reduction itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! You are Completely correct, my math was incorrect.  The rref matrix should have been [[1,0,0,-1],[0,1,0,-1],[0,0,1,-1],[0,0,0,0]], and the eigenvector sensibly works out to be [[1],[1],[1],[1]].

Comment: The reason the computer program failed was b/c the matrix is ill-conditioned.  Thanks again!